# Firebase SDK pass object to GTM and GA

Tags: ios, firebase, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, firebase-analytics

Goal - send data to Google Analytics (don't care about Firebase Analytics).

In my App I am replacing GTM SDK (v3) with a newer version: Firebase SDK (v5) and wondering if I can pass an object as an event parameter. I.e

```
[FIRAnalytics logEventWithName:@"share_image"
                    parameters:@{
                                 @"mediaItem": { 
                                   @"title":title, @"url":url
                                   }
                                 }];
```

I need *mediaItem* to be an object (dictionary) with two keys (*title* and *url* which are both strings). Now when I am passing this, I can access this object and it's properties in **GTM** using something like *{{mediaItemDataLayerVar}}.title* however the debug console of my app throws a warning that I should only send NSNumber or NSString as an event parameters. Documentation page says the same.

While it obviously work (passing *NSDictionary*) the warning get me worried as this may stop working in the future releases.

Does anyone has a similar problem? How have you dealt with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had the same situation.

After a little digging - passing dictionaries as event key parameters to GTM via Firebase+GTM SDK works without any issues. 
Any attempt to get more information from google or roadmap on what we can expect in the future as a result of merging Firebase and GTM SDKs wasn't successful.

Basically, you can do that at your own risk, but there is a chance that this will be officially supported in the next versions of the Firebase+GTM SDK or replaced with a similar approach used for Enhanced ECommerce.

While dictionaries work - I could not get arrays to work.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Analytics SDK won't accept other data structure other than string or number. It might pass to GTM but Analytics won't log such parameters and thus you won't see it in the dashboard. You can log more complicated data structure in Analytics (see [enhanced ecommerce](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/ios/v5/enhanced-ecommerce)) which allows you to pass an **array** of parameters if that what you want. See the link for examples.

Comment: >but Analytics won't log such parameters
It actually is, if I process the parameter correctly in GTM it is getting logged to Google Analytics. Your response is probably correct to Firebase SDK

Comment: Yes, I am referring to Firebase Analytics. Google Analytics is different though.

Comment: thanks adbitx. In this project I don't care about Firebase Analytics. Just Google Analytics (GA). And it does work, so I can send complex data structures to GTM and read it and send correctly to GA, but I am also getting a warning..